# .net Core 5.0. While instantiating class in controller: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration'

Tags: c#, ado.net, connection-string, webapi

In my .net Core 5.0 project, i am working on a webapi and am getting the following error while instantiating my DatabaseLayer class in my controller.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'configuration' of 'DatabaseLayer.DatabaseLayer(IConfiguration)'

All the other examples that i have seen so far are using EFF and dbContext class but in my case i am using ado.net.

```
Here is my code so far:
My connection string is saved in appsettings.json:
*************************************************
"ConnectionStrings": {
"MyConnection": "data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True"
 }

    ********************************************
This is what i have in my Startup.cs class:

var conn = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
        services.AddSingleton(conn);



********************************************
In my DBAccessLayer.cs i have this:


using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;



namespace ProjectDL.Models
{
public class DatabaseLayer
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public DatabaseLayer(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

   public JsonResult GetUsersList()
    {code here}



********************************************
This is what i have in my controller class:
*********************************************
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using ProjectDL.Models;

namespace ProjectAPI.Controllers
{

[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    public UsersController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this._configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var objDepartments = new DatabaseLayer();<---This is where i am getting the error
        return objUsers.GetUsersList();
    }

***************************************
```

Any help in this matter will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `new DatabaseLayer(_configuration)`

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong constructor for the `DatabaseLayer` class initialization. In `DatabaseLayer` you have the constructor:

```
public DatabaseLayer(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration; //setting the IConfiguration
}                                   //for the class
```

But in the controller you are initializing a new object without passing the correct parameters into the constructor. You have to do:

```
var objDepartments = new DatabaseLayer(_configuration);
```

Or if you don't want to pass in a IConfiguration object into the `DatabaseLayer` class, you could create a second empty constructor in that class:

```
public DatabaseLayer() { }
```

Which you would probably want to avoid because it seems that you will likely need that `IConfiguration` parameter.